# N8N: Remove JSON Key in output

Tags: javascript, json, n8n

I am trying to remove the json key in my output file. What is the best approach to do this? not sure how to achieve this.  I want to return the array of data with all values. Not necessarily 1 value.

This is a link to my N8N post:
[Manipulate JSON File Structure to endpoint](https://community.n8n.io/t/manipulate-json-file-structure-to-endpoint/24418/3)

below is my structure

current output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 21428
    }
  ]
}
```

and i want to remove {"data": to get this outcome.

```
[
   {
     "id": 21428
   }
]
```

[image]

[image]

i have tried changing my item list to split output but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reassign the output with the value of `data` object:

```
output = output.data;
```

```js
let output = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 21428
    }
  ]
};
output= output.data;
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @Manun thanks for the response. I want to return the array of data with all values. Not necessarily 1 value. How would that look?

Comment: @CodeOfArms, above solution will return all the values present in the data array!